# Android: Deleting characters in EditText with TextWatcher still shows characters in suggestions

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-input-method

In my activity I have an EditText to capture a file name. I am using a TextWatcher to prevent users from entering certain characters that I don't want them to use in their filename. Essentially I only want users to enter in the following characters: [a-zA-Z_0-9].

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable text) {
    String textStr = text.toString();
    int length = text.length();

    if (!Pattern.matches("\\w*", textStr)) {
        text.delete(length-1, length);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Adding more code
in onCreate(...)

```
fileNameEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.UploadPhoto_fileNameEditText);
fileNameEditText.addTextChangedListener(this);
```

in layout xml file

```
<EditText
 android:id="@+id/UploadPhoto.fileNameEditText"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginBottom="20sp"
 android:layout_marginRight="10sp"
 android:layout_toRightOf="@id/UploadPhoto.fileNameLabel"/>
```

This works perfectly by preventing users from entering in things like "\" and ".". The problem that I'm having is that if they type these characters they show up in the word suggestions box. Its kind of annoying because if you try to delete a character using backspace, it deletes from the suggestion first (even though the character doesn't show up in EditText box).

How do you prevent the unwanted characters from showing up in the word suggestiong box?

See screen shot below. Notice that the "-" (hyphen) appears in the suggestion box, but not in the EditText. Also notice that there is another valid character in the suggestion box after the hyphen that also does not show up in the EditText. This essentially blocks the user from entering in more text until they delete the hyphen, even though its not in the EditText.

UPDATE: The same issue arises and can be reproduced by using an InputFilter instead of a TextWatcher.

UPDATE: **I'd like to clarify that my goal is not to suppress the Suggestions altogether. The issue is that when you prevent specific characters from appearing in the EditText, they still show up in the Suggestions. My goal (which the bounty is for) is to prevent the same specific characters from appearing in the Suggestions.**

[image]

Comment: Note that the above image comes from the emulator running a 2.3.3 AVD.  I've also tried turning off the word suggestions using inputType="textNoSuggestions" but that's not working. The word suggestions still show up.

Comment: Odd indeed. While trying multiple combinations of input types like "textNoSuggestions|textFilter" didn't work on the 2.3.3 AVD. However, using inputType="textVisiblePassword" worked.

Comment: I'd still like to know how to filter out text from the suggestions though, so my original question still stands. If the text isn't in the text box it shouldn't be in the suggestions in my opinion. Does anyone think thats a bug?

Comment: I'm starting to think that this is a bug.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an [InputFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html) to restrict some characters in `Edittext`

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() { 
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, 
Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) { 
                for (int i = start; i < end; i++) { 
                        if (!Character.isLetterOrDigit(source.charAt(i))) { 
                                return ""; 
                        } 
                } 
                return null; 
        } 
}; 

edit.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, using InputFilter, I am still able to reproduce the behavior I described above. Characters that I restrict in the EditText don't show up in the EditText, but they do show up in the Suggestions which causes other issues. Namely, if there's an invalid character in the suggestion it prevents further input into the EditText until the character is deleted from the Suggesion box. I do appreciate the pointer to the InputFilter interface, I was unaware of that one, they seem quite similar to each other.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the emulator doesn't support the textNoSuggestions, and the corresponding FLAG (TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS). It's realy anoying, but hey: you're not developing for emulator users, you shouldn't be preoccupied with this, it'll work fine on allmost all devices.

(Note that this flag is available only from API level 5)

Comment: So this solves the problem of suppressing the text suggestions altogether, but as I've mentioned, I've got that under control already by using the "textVisiblePassword" flag. However, this doesn't answer my question about how to prevent unwanted characters from appearing in the text suggestions, as it does in the screen shot above. My current feeling is that this is a bug...

Comment: I'm thinking more of a missing feature. It would be hard and time consuming to filter out all items from the dictionary that are not conform to the filters - sometimes set dynamically - of the text field.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is more buggy then missing feature. If you use the TextWatcher or InputFilter to filter out text from the EditText (say for example "-" character), and then you enter in a "-", it prevents you from adding text to the EditText until you delete the "-", even though "-" isn't displayed in the EditText. I'm not saying the solution is to apply the filter to the dictionary search as well, I'm saying that the Suggestion box should base its search input on the text that appears in the EditText, since the "-" didn't appear in the EditText, it shouldn't appear in the Suggestion box.

Answer (score 0):

We can do that in the layout xml file and achive what you have asked in an easy way, insert the line

```
android:numeric="your custom elements"
android:digits="your custom elments"
android:inputType="your custom elements"
```

when you implement these then you will be able to type the words that you want to.

Comment: I don't think this solves the problem of preventing unwanted characters from appearing in the Suggestions.

Comment: yes.. Have u tried that, by doing that only relevant characters will be coming in the edit text. eg: android:digits="0123456789" by giving this the input of the edit text will be numbers only no other inputs will be taken inside. like wise we custom the edit text.

Comment: No, this doesn't solve the problem. The problem isn't restricting characters in the EditText, I can do that with a TextWatcher or InputFilter. The problem is that even though you restrict unwanted characters in the EditText, they still appear in the word Suggestions (see the screen shot, you can clearly see a '-' in the word suggestions even though I have restricted it from the EditText).